# Adding string from .txt file into a command – for macro

Tags: awk

I am processing multiple file which are saved as

```
N.YMDH.U.A.1.SAC    
N.YMDH.U.D.2.SAC  
N.YMDH.U.E.3.SAC
```

and so on...
I also have a `.txt` file which looks as follows named `YMDH_arrival_time.txt`

```
N.YMDH.U.A.1.SAC    5.000   7.000  
N.YMDH.U.D.2.SAC    7.321   4.313  
N.YMDH.U.E.3.SAC    3.243   7.876
```

and so on ....
I want to write a script so, if the file name matches `$1`, then, do a command on the file which involves the input of `$2` of the same row.

---

What I've been attempting
 #### I want the $file to be read 1 by 1 so temp_file.txt is only 1 row long then the same file is read later and the value from the .txt file can be added then the process repeated ect.

```
for file in /Documents/Scaling/YMDH/*.SAC do;

awk '{$1 ~ /$file/ {print $1  $2 $3}' /Documents/Scaling/YMDH_arrival_time.txt > temp_file.txt 

#### in hope to find the row which matches and print that row into a new txt file

SAC <<EOF   

r $file   
CHNDHR T (I want to put the value of $2 of temp_file.txt here)   
w $file.done  
quit   
EOF   
done
```

---

any help will be appreciated or an alternate method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your `YMDH_arrival_time.txt` file has fixed format `<string> <number> <number>` - it's enough to use the following **grep** + **cat** approach:

```
grep -f <(cat /Documents/Scaling/YMDH/*.SAC) YMDH_arrival_time.txt > temp_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To fit your existing approach you'd just use

variable=$(cat temp_file.txt)

However check comments on RomanPerekhrest's approach.